# I need to define 3 kinds of messages in omnet

Tags: ios-simulator, simulation, iot, omnet++, fog

I want to define 3 kinds of messages in omnet
I know I have to use messagekind but I couldnt
please help me
I want help message, control message and jobs, which jobs should be processed
thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the three message classes, in a class, say DemoLayer, you need 2 changes in .h file  and 1 in .cc file.

In .h file,
under the public specifier add

```
enum DemoMessageKinds {
    SEND_DATA-MESSAGE,
    SEND_CONTROL-MESSAGE,
    SEND_JOB-MESSAGE
};
```

and under protected specifier add

```
void handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) override;
```

In .cc file, add

```
void DemoLayer::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg)
{   
   switch (msg->getKind()) 
   {
      case SEND_DATA-MESSAGE: 
      {
        ControlMessage* cm = new ControlMessage();
        ....//
```

For an example, check this https://github.com/sommer/veins/tree/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p

Comment: Hi. If you found my answer working, please mark it as answered.

Comment: hi sure dear, but i want to define these types for all module, I mean in this way do I have a personal message just for a especial module?

Comment: Yes. You are right. handleSelfMessage () is used to handle messages within the module. Please use handleMessage( ) if you want all modules to get the generated message(s).

Comment: I used the method name as handleMessage( ) referring to the tic-toc example.

Comment: how ?i dont know how mark this

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Creating of messages is described in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:first-msg-class) as well as in [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#44-defining-our-message-class).
In short:

1. You have to create a new `.msg` file, for example `ControlMessage.msg`, with your content, for example:

   ```
   message ControlMessage {
     int someAddress;
     // ...
   }
   ```
2. In your C++ code you have to add the following line:

   ```
   #include "ControlMessage_m.h"
   ```

(during compilation `ControlMessage_m.h` is automatically created from `ControlMessage.msg`)